# My Bitcoin transaction remained unconfirmed for 20 days now

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions, replace-by-fee

I sent a bitcoin transaction from one of my wallets into another wallet meant for trading. Its been 20 days now and the transaction remained unconfirmed. Please I need help because I sent this coin from my blockchain.com wallet. I need step by step assistance on how to use the RBF or CPFP on blockchain.com wallet

Comment: I need help on how to either use the RBF or CPFP on the blockchain.com wallet

Comment: @Awales if you click the [edit] link and change the title of your question above to specifically  *"How do I use RBF or CPFP in the Blockchain.com wallet"* your question might be kept open and answered. You ought to be able to get help from support at blockchain.com too